# Packaging Node and Project Directory in .exe and running package.json scripts

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is there a way I can package my node.js project along with node into an .exe that runs some node modules CLI scripts like "npm start".

I've looked into [pkg](https://github.com/vercel/pkg#readme) but it seems it seems it can only run from a .js entry point. I've tried using child_process but this also failed.

My question is is there a simpler way of packaging my project for a non-tech person to run that does not have node js on their machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hacky solution I came up with is to create a folder with the [node binaries](https://nodejs.org/dist/)
make sure node.exe is in the root along with node_modules and npm.cmd.. etc. combine your projects node_modules folder with the folder you got from the node.js archive file. and at last include your other project source files.

now you can cd into the root of the folder and use commands as "npm start" "node script.js" as we made it portable (a portable node environment in the folder)

for further automation you can create a .bat file with the commands that need to be runned.